# $ es indefinido en unit test mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy usando `mocha` para realizar mis test unitarios de la capa web, y me genera el error:

> $ is not defined

¿Me puede estar faltando importar algo mas para que me reconozca el signo `$` de `jQuery`?

El código de mi test es :

```
var assert = require('assert');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var utils = require('../js/utils');


describe('UtilsSuite', function() {

    describe('#isUsuarioAdministradorExperto c2', function() {
        before(function () {
            global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
        });

        it('Cuando el estado no pertence entre los disponible retorna vacio ', function (){
            console.log(utils.mostrarFechaSolucion('02/02/2002','SITIO_GSM_NORMAL'));
            assert.equal("",utils.mostrarFechaSolucion('02/02/2002','SITIO_GSM_NORMAL'));
        });
    });


});
```

y el código de mi función es :

```
    exports.mostrarFechaSolucion = function (fechaSolucion, estadoTecnico) {
    return ($.inArray(estadoTecnico, estadosFechaSolucion) > -1) ?
         "<tr><td class='encabezado'>Fecha soluci&oacute;n:</td><td class='datosSitio'>" + fechaSolucion + "</td></tr>" : "";
};
```

Comment: Mientras buscas la solución, podrías ir usando JavaScript puro. El `$.inArray` se puede reemplazar con `estadosFechaSolucion.includes(estadoTecnico)`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede ser que no se esta iniciando jQuery porque no encuentra la API DOM. Trata con [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global) inyectará document, window y otras API DOM a tu entorno Node.js.

```
> this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')(); 
> global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

También podes intentar poner eso al inicio de tu test mocha.